# Excel return most recent cell change

Tags: excel

Without macros, Excel can return the most recent entry.

Imagine if I have insert values in A1 then in A4 then in A2. In B1 I would have a formula that give me the last modified cell. In this case it would show A2 on B1.

Can this be made?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This post and discussion](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/08/09/cell-worksheet-function/) at Daily Dose of Excel might be helpful.